# After what time I can ask a duplicate question to my another question which I've just deleted?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I asked a question which haven't got any answer so I want to try again. But asking a new one it even with changes looks like duplicate to the old one so system don't let me to ask it. So I deleted the old one but anyway system recognize it as a duplicate to that question. How long must it take before I can ask this new question? Is that deal in caching?

Comment: **never** ask a new one, edit your old question if you want to add more details or keep waiting

Comment: @Temani but after time my question go down in the list so people will come to it less and less. I don't need the answer on it after a year. I've just deleted the old as if it never existed

Comment: and you think that the *new* asked question will get a different result? If the question is the same it will be treated the same. Deleting and reposting the same question simply to have it on the top of the list is an *abuse* of the system.

Comment: You could try to earn [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) and then set a bounty on that question.

Comment: "I don't need the answer on it after a year." well, giving you an answer is not the main goal here - instead this site tries to build a library of knowledge for future users with the same problem. Also did you consider that by reposting your question, you will bereave other posts their time on the front page - why should your question be more important than others?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It might actually be treated worse if it is a repost. It will probably be closed quicker, downvoted more and it might even be deleted by 20k+

Comment: Have you read what [Einstein wrote](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/einstein-s-parable-of-quantum-insanity/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CInsanity%20is%20doing%20the%20same,usually%20attributed%20to%20Albert%20Einstein.) about repeating what you've already done and expecting it to turn out differently? If your question didn't work, figure out why and change it.

Comment: A deleted question still exists, it will always count against your ability to ask new questions, enough deleted questions will eventually result in a question ban.  **You should improve your current question.** If you ask the exact same question it will just be closed

Comment: @Alex if you can't wait and *need* the answer **now**.... Stack is the wrong place, unfortunately for your predicament

Comment: @Patrice don't you know such service designed to solve the problem of the OP?)

Comment: @AlexBurla - you know that when you edit a post, it is bumped to the top in the "active" tab? A lot of users frequent it, so editing the old question is not a vain effort. Just remember: **do not edit just to bump**. Add references, improve grammar and clarity, show additional research, etc. Also, if you are talking about a post you made 19 hours ago, it is not even enough time to start worrying, let alone deleting the question.

Comment: @Alex a free one? no clue. You can likely find someone you'll pay to get it done in a given amount of time, though

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. If you feel that your question has not received enough attention, you can add a bounty to it (once you have enough reputation). You can also edit to improve the question and make sure that the tags are correct.